# Create React App builds empty document (blank screen) with react-router and firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I get a white screen on my deployed react webapp, it worked perfectly before. I tried everything I could find here but it didn t worked.
Below is the link to my website : https://numbr-d1a20.firebaseapp.com/

Change the homepage, look for error in the console, clear my cache and a lot more...

Below is my package.json

```
{
      "name": "numbr",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.3.1",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "firebase": "^6.3.4",
        "mysql": "^2.17.1",
        "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
        "nodemon": "^1.19.1",
        "react": "^16.8.6",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
        "react-native-indicators": "^0.13.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
        "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
        "recompose": "^0.30.0"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
         "extends": "react-app"
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
      }
}
```

I expect to see my sign in page and not a blank screen.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you please show the code?

Comment: @Phillip below is the link the git repo of the project : https://github.com/rosanche/Numbr ;)
I just took of the firebase.js file because I have my private config in it.

Answer (score 0):

The const 'condition' in the connectScreen component is undefined. Your authentication logic then prevents the component from rendering. Test what happens when you set `const condition = true` and see if it works then.

Comment: No I tried, but condition is a function, I used it in my with-autorization.js file to verify that my user is connected before showing him my components.

Below is the error :
TypeError: condition is not a function
(anonymous function)
src/components/session/with-autorization.js:30
  27 | 
  28 | render() {
  29 |   return (
> 30 |     <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
     | ^  31 |       {authUser =>
  32 |         condition(authUser) ? <Component {...this.props} /> : null
  33 |       }